# Creating a list by searching for substrings in python

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have two lists:

```
names = ['albert', 'bob', 'charlie']
padded_names = ['albertGARBAGE', 'jamesTRASH', 'bobREFUSE', 'timRUBBISH', 'charlieWASTE']
```

I want a list whose members are `['albertGARBABE', 'bobREFUSE', 'charlieWASTE']`

Looking at other threads, I see similar tasks accomplished using the `filter()` function, but I don't know how to apply that to lists.  I might also be able to iterate the first list and use `str.find()`, but I'm having limited luck with that as well.

In actuality, `padded_names` is a list of lists, but I can manipulate that.

Efficiency isn't a concern of mine, so ugly solutions are valid :)  And unfortunately, the system I'm working on is limited to python 2.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it pretty simply:

```
filtered_list = []
for name in names:
    for padded_name in padded_names:
        if padded_name.find(name) >= 0:
            filtered_list.append(padded_name)
```

And can be converted into a nice python one liner:

```
filtered_list = [padded_name for padded_name in padded_names if any(padded_name.find(name) >= 0 for name in names)]
```

If you want to use the filter function, you need to design your own method that will return true on your condition:

```
def test(padded_name):
    names = ['albert', 'bob', 'charlie']
    return any(padded_name.find(name) >= 0 for name in names)        

filtered_names = filter(test,padded_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

The filter version would look something like:

```
filter( lambda x : any( name in x for name in names ), padded_names )
```

Filter takes two arguments, a function (1st arg) you're applying to the (iterable) data set (2nd set).

This uses a lambda to create a custom function that checks if the name occurs in each of the names in padded_names.

Answer (score 0):

using `list comprehension` and `startswith`: one liner

```
>>> [ x for x in padded_names for y in names if x.startswith(y) ]
['albertGARBAGE', 'bobREFUSE', 'charlieWASTE']
```